# I am calling the mean function. But I am getting TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, pandas

My objective is to find the mean of a column (`raised_amount_usd`) in a dataframe (say `master_frame`). However when I try to do so I get a TypeError

```
    master_frame['raised_amount_usd'].mean()
```

I expected the code to successfully execute and show the output. However I get:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: So what's *in* `master_frame['raised_amount_usd']`? All numbers?

Comment: Yes. all numbers and some empty values

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to try and fill the empty values with 0. 
You can do that using 
`master_frame['raised_amount_usd'] = master_frame['raised_amount_usd'].fillna(0)`

Comment: Please could you post the code for the column. It would also be helpful to check the datatype of the entries in the column.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following worked 
master_frame['raised_amount_usd'].astype(float).mean()